# It is possible to rotate the PCB view in Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad

I do not want to rotate the parts (that is easy by selecting all and click on rotate icon), only the view.

Comment: Rotate or flip/mirror?

Comment: Not mirror, but rotate 90, 180 or 270 degrees because I have a lot of harness connected and can not rotate the PCB so it is difficult to find components or specific pin in a large connector

Comment: "...not rotate the PCB so it is difficult to find components or specific pin in a large connector " - What has the connector size got to do with the PCB view?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not possible.

> It has not been implemented.

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/eagle-forum/feature-request-turn-eagle-view/td-p/8980757